# grunt shell create database

Tags: mysql, shell, gruntjs

I'm trying to use grunt with grunt-shell to create a database.
The problem is that: if I create It from shell this line works fine:

```
mysql -uroot -pmypass -e "create database test"
```

Instead if I use grunt and grunt-shell it doesn't work like this:

```
 shell: {
            install_db: {
                options: {
                    stdout: true,
                    stderr: true
                },
                command: [
                    'ssh user@demo.server.it mysql -uroot -pmypass -e "create database test"',
                ].join("&&")
            }
        }
```

"it doesn't work" mean that print out the list of arguments for `mysql` like this:

```
Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
  --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
                      'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
                      and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
                      --disable-auto-rehash.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)
  -A, --no-auto-rehash 
...
```

I have also tried:

```
'ssh user@demo.server.it mysql -uroot -pmypass -e \"create database test\"',

'ssh user@demo.server.it mysql -uroot -pmypass -e create database test',

'ssh user@demo.server.it mysql -uroot -p -e create database test',
```

and many other, same problem print out list of argument of `mysql` command and it doesn't create the database.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the problem, with mysqladmin it works fine like this:

```
'ssh user@demo.server.it mysqladmin -uroot -pmypass create test',
```